# Value from Session Storage as a number?

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I have two values on my html: "Money" and "Time", and those values come from Session Storage, depending on what the person filled previously in another html page. So lets say the person filled that they need to pay $100 in 2 days.

So the idea would be for the result to be displayed on my HTML like:

- $50
- $50

If the number of days increased to 4, for example, the result would be:

- $25
- $25
- $25
- $25

When i hard code random numbers as the values for "Money" and "Time", the result is exactly what i need, just like the example above. But whenever i try to get the values from Session Storage, the result is always ONE topic of the `<li>` that i wanted to create, just like the example below:

Money: 100 / Days: 2

- $50

My code so far:

```html
<p id="money-value"></p>
<p id="time-value"></p>
<div id="payments"></div>
<script>
   const displayMoney = document.getElementById("money-value");
   const storedMoney = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("Money"));
   window.addEventListener("load", () => {
       displayMoney.innerHTML =  "Money: " + storedMoney
   });
   
   const displayTime = document.getElementById("time-value");
   const storedTime = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("Time"));
   window.addEventListener("load", () => {
       displayTime.innerHTML =  "Time: " + storedTime
   });
   
   var calc = storedMoney / storedTime;
   
   for (let i = 0; i < storedTime; i++) {
      var list = document.createElement("li");
      list.innerText = `${calc}`;
      document.getElementById("payments").appendChild(list);
   }
   
</script>
```

**TL;DR**

What i'm really struggling with, is to make the `<li>` display the payments in the same number of topics as the number of days.

Comment: calc = ${storedMoney / storedTime}?

Comment: do a console.log of your sessionStorage values and see if they're expected values. Also if you're using Chrome, in dev tools select "Application" tab and you can view your session storage.

Comment: Just updated the question with the calc. I forgot to copy it. When i console.log the values, they appear as the expected values. I even console logged the "typeof" the values, and they are logged as numbers.

Comment: In your example should it not be Money: 100 / Days: 2 results in 2 li's with $50?

Comment: Everything checks out, if I set session storage to the values it validates correctly for me. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/Pellay/2jzmecoh/9/

Comment: Exaclty! It should display 2 li's. 
For some reason that's not happening here. So did it display the 2 li's for you?

Comment: Yes, check my JSFiddle. Also, for future reference, it's worth trying out your code in fiddle to test various scenarios. Helpful for snagging specific issues. But from the looks of it, everything is correct. Might be worth you posting your code for storing the values too.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. For some reason i typed the wrong number for the margin, on my css. So the other li element wasn't being displayed, despite being there!
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem. It's always something silly when there's not logical reason it won't be working!